# Error: "Program type already present: androidx.versionedparcelable.CustomVersionedParcelable"

Tags: android, gradle, error-handling, android-gradle-plugin, runtime-error

I am having trouble with the following Error --> **Error: Program type already present: androidx.versionedparcelable.CustomVersionedParcelable**

When I click in Build errors it shows me this:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: androidx.versionedparcelable.CustomVersionedParcelable","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I don't understand what it is causing this problem because I am using Parcelable library but never caused me this type of error.

This is my project's gradle file.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    // Lottie
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.8.0'
    //Gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    //Dagger 2
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.18'
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.18"
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.18'
    //Asyncjob
    implementation 'com.arasthel:asyncjob-library:1.0.3'
    //Butterknife
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-rc1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-rc1'
}
```

This is my Build panel in Android Studio

[image]
Any thoughts?? Thanks!!

**UPDATE (12-1-2018)**

I think I have found the answer for this problem. I read that all the support libraries are going to migrate to androidx library.

So I have read in the Android Developers Documentation and explain how to migrate all the `android.support.` libraries to androidx.

You only have to go to Android Studio and make **Refactor >> Migrate to AndroidX** from the menu bar.

This is the link for more information **-->** [Android Developers Documentation (Migrate to Androidx)](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Comment: a rebuild was good enough for me after using the `Migrate to AndroidX` option

Answer (score 4):

Add this in your `gradle.properties` file

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: this is almost the solution I have explained in the Update but my solution is made by Android Studio automatically.
btw Thanks!

Comment: What if we don't want to use AndroidX because of conflicts with other librairies ?

Comment: @Mayoul see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Only this solution works for me after a long time of search.

Android Studio Menu -> Build -> Rebuild Project.

Source [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58276441/6316770).

Comment: This above should be the selected answer!  Worked for me and I tried a lot of stuff~. Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

**Problem:**

> Error: Program type already present:
>
> androidx.versionedparcelable.CustomVersionedParcelable

**Solution:** Add this in your gradle.properties file in the top.

```
android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true
```

Your Project will migrate to androidx with no error during build time