# React Native Error while generating the main dex list

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I tried most the answers provided in stackoverflow as well as github from adding

```
multiDexEnabled true 
dexOptions{javaMaxHeapSize "4g"}
```

but there was no luck, I think my problem is with the dependencies. The actual error I am getting when I run cd android ./gradlew clean then gradlew assembldebug or react-native run-android is

> What went wrong: Execution failed for
>   task':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while
>   generating the main dex list.

Building in Android Studio shows the following Error:

> Program type already present:
>   androidx.versionedparcelable.CustomVersionedParcelable

adding

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

causes more problems since most of my react-native libraries that I used in my project not translated to androidx

> Execution failed for task
>   ':react-native-navigation:compileReactNative57_5DebugJavaWithJavac'

so my intention is to draw back from androidx, is there a way to do so?

Comment: can you provide error log, and as you fail in assembldebug  can you install that,bear in mind that using debug build in react will give users access ti devMenu

Comment: I just did provided the error above plz check, thanks

Comment: no provide complete log, another good practice is using android studio which give more hint

Comment: Android Studio gives this Error .  Program type already present: androidx.versionedparcelable.CustomVersionedParcelable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: "Program type already present: androidx.versionedparcelable.CustomVersionedParcelable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53570454/error-program-type-already-present-androidx-versionedparcelable-customversion)

Comment: please read my comment to your answer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a day of research, couldn't find a correct way to roll back from androidx and translating all react-native dependencies to androidx manually seems a tedious job but thanks to this library [jetifier](https://github.com/mikehardy/jetifier) I was able to do so just by running

```
npm i --save-dev jetifier
npx jetify
```