# Android - Program type already present com.transition.R while importing ViewPager2 library

Tags: androidx, android-viewpager2

**`Gradle`** is throwing Program type already present: `androidx.transition.R"` after importing `androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-beta02`

```
implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-beta02'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: androidx.transition.R","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
```

**Expected outcome:** `Gradle` should compile with no error

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was facing similar problem, Rebuilding the project resolved it.

Android Studio Menu -> Build -> Rebuild Project.

Comment: Thank you. I had to remove my .gradle and build folder, then click rebuild :)

Comment: The combination of these tips was the only thing that solved it for me \o/. Not even "Invalidate caches and restart" did it.

Answer (score 3):

actually in my case run `./gradlew clean` inside android directory worked.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

First, try:

Build -> Clean Project.

It's faster than Rebuild and except once, always fixed my problems. If it doesn't work, try to rebuild it as @Rahul [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58276441/5136131).

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly due to build issue.

Either

- remove the old build folder with `./gradlew clean`  inside the android directory, or
- simply remove `android/app/build` folder